# Beginner: LEFT JOIN not doing what it should?

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble with a really simple left join statement that's driving me nuts
I wanted to count the numbers of orders from each customer, that's fine, but I want to display the name, and I'm joining with the customers table and trying to select the name and it says that CustomerName is not part of an aggregate function, it's really weird.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName as 'Name',
COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count'
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
```

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That is invalid standard SQL (and that GROUP BY usage will be rejected by most DBMS)

Comment: Tip: Use a nested query as the left side of the JOIN.

Comment: How is GROUP BY invalid? I'm using this, for learning: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

Comment: The fields used in a group by should appear in the select statement for the query to work

Comment: Another example why w3fools is a bad resource. `customername` is not part of the `group by` and thus it has to appear in an aggregate function. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=330d69f27f5b9db6ac7bec33623d3ee0

Answer (score 3):

You need to count the rows from the `orders` table, and the left join should be in the other direction:

```
SELECT c.customerid, 
       c.CustomerName as "Name",
       COUNT(o.customerid) AS "Order Count"
FROM Customers c
  LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.CustomerID = cs.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.customername;
```

`count()` will ignore NULL values that come into the result due to the outer join so it will count the number of orders for each customers. Customers without orders will be show with a zero count.

Comment: i think there is a typo in your left join sentence.. `LEFT JOIN Orders o ON o.Cust...`

Answer (score 0):

Modify as below. column used in group by clause should be in column queried in select clause

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName as 'Name',
COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count'
FROM Orders
LEFT JOIN Customers
    ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerName
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `CustomerName` in `Group BY` instead of `CustomerID`

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName as 'Name', COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count'
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerName
```

If you are using `SQL Server` then try using `OVER()` without `Group BY`

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName as 'Name', COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Customers.CustomerName ORDER BY Customers.CustomerName)AS 'Order Count'
FROM Orders LEFT JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just reordered your query,please try this it will definitely work for you.

```
SELECT Customers.CustomerName as 'Name',
COUNT(*) AS 'Order Count'
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.CustomerID=Orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to get all the columns in the customers table is to use a correlated subquery:

```
select c.*,   -- or whatever columns you want
       (select count(*)
        from orders o
        where o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       ) as order_count
from customers c;
```

Because this avoids the outer `GROUP BY`, this also has the advantage of having better performance in most databases, particularly with an index on `orders(CustomerId)`. Plus, it returns `0` if the customer has no orders.  And, it allows you to choose any or all of the columns from `Customers`.

The correct way to get the counts you want is to count a column from `Orders`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, c.CustomerID, 
       COUNT(o.CustomerId) AS Order_Count
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName;
```

Notes:

- The `Customers` table goes first in the `LEFT JOIN` because presumably you want all rows in `Customers`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- Do not use single quotes for column aliases, even if your database supports it.  The best method is to choose aliases that do not need to be supported.
- Include the `CustomerId` in the logic, just in case two customers have the same name.
- Count a column from `Orders` so you get a count of `0` for customers with no orders.